# iOS KeyboardManager not working when the application is turned on a second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a strange problem. The keyboard works when I have the app connected to Xcode. If app turn off and on again, the keyboard with UITextView and UITextField no longer works... but UISearchField works.

I use this methods:

```
- (void)addKeyboardNotifications {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(questionCellTextViewBeginEditing:) name:@"QuestionCellTextViewBeginEditingNotification" object:nil];
}
```

For example keyboardWillShow in Objective-C look like:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [_tableView setContentBottomInset:[Tools keyboardHeightFromNotification:notification]];
    
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    }];
}
```

And I use Swift version in a few places in app:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(sender: Notification) {
        keyboardHeight = (sender.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect).size.height
        
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            
            if (appDelegate.window?.safeAreaInsets.top)! > CGFloat(0.0) || appDelegate.window?.safeAreaInsets != .zero {
                keyboardHeight -= (appDelegate.window?.safeAreaInsets.bottom)!
            }
        }
        
        let y = self.tableView.contentOffset.y + keyboardHeight
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: y)
        
        self.textViewContainerBottomConstraint?.constant = keyboardHeight
        
        self.view?.layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

I am wondering about this log printed in console when I terminated app:

`[27682:19912067] [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x7fa4e304d400, UIKeyboardImpl) that is not in a visible window requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.`

Do you know where is problem? I have no idea how to test an application without being debugged in Xcode.

Comment: Does it work correctly on a device? The simulator will attach your keyboard which can have strange side effects but you can use a device to test or turn that off in the simulator and also see if that makes a difference. In the simulator, switch off I/O > Keyboard > Connect hardware keyboard and see if it works.

Comment: @skaak I tested on a physical device too.

Comment: I do something vaguely similar - also with constraints to change layout based on keyboard but I use keyboard*Did*Show/Hide ... maybe give that a try. Not entirely sure what you mean with the keyboard no longer works?